# Passed params drop after failed submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my app I pass parameters from one controller to another

Firstly I'm creating `Company` object and pass its `id` in parameters in redirecting link

companies_controller:

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @company = Company.new
  end

  def create
    @company = current_user.companies.build(company_params)
    if @company.save
      redirect_to new_constituent_path(:constituent, company_id: @company.id)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def company_params
      params.require(:company).permit(:name)
    end

end
```

After successfully `Company` saving I'm redirected to creating a `Constituent` object. I fill `company_id` or `entrepreneur_id` with parameters passed in link `http://localhost:3000/constituents/new.constituent?company_id=9` for example

constituents/new:

```
  = simple_form_for @constituent do |f|
    = f.input :employees
    - if params[:entrepreneur_id]
      = f.hidden_field :entrepreneur_id, value: params[:entrepreneur_id]
    - elsif params[:company_id]
      = f.hidden_field :company_id, value: params[:company_id]
    = f.button :submit
```

constituents_controller:

```
class ConstituentsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @constituent = Constituent.new
  end

  def create
    @constituent = Constituent.create(constituent_params)
    if @constituent.save
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def constituent_params
      params.require(:constituent).permit(:employees, :company_id, :entrepreneur_id)
    end

end
```

The problem is parameters I passed in link is dropping after failed attempt to save `@constituent` and `company_id` or `entrepreneur_id` is `nil`. How can I fix it?

Comment: I don't know if this is related to your problem, but shouldn't your link be `/constituents/new/constituent?company_id=9` instead of `/constituents/new.constituent?company_id=9 `

Answer (score 0):

This happens because after you submit your form, there are no `params[:company_id] = 9` anymore. After `render :new` is done, you will have `params[:constituent][:company_id] = 9`.

So, to solve this problem, you need to send not this get request to new Constituent:

```
http://localhost:3000/constituents/new?company_id=9
```

But something like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/constituents/new?constituent[company_id]=9
```

Your view will become a little bit more ugly, to avoid error if `params[:constituent]` not exist:

```
- if params[:constituent]
  - if params[:constituent][:entrepreneur_id]
    = f.hidden_field :entrepreneur_id, value: params[:constituent][:entrepreneur_id]
  - elsif params[:constituent][:company_id]
    = f.hidden_field :company_id, value: params[constituent][:company_id]
```

Comment: And if only one belongs_to association is valid (id Constituent can't have both belongs_to filled) it's better to use polymorphic association.